# Convert html form data into ArrayList

Tags: html, forms, parsing, servlets, web-applications

Hello to the community!

I would like an end-user to enter data, in the format of a comma delimited list of numbers, into a web application.  Then I would like to be able to perform an operation on that list and return a result to the end-user.

I have been playing around with HTML5 text forms and GET/POST methods. I can create a text form to gather the input and I can use request.getParameter() to collect the data, but I cannot figure out how to convert the user-input into a format I can work with.  I would like to convert it to an ArrayList of Integers or Doubles.

I know this is a very broad question, but I would appreciate any recommendations you may have.  Perhaps I am moving in the wrong direction altogether.

Here is my servlet code right now:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class getMod12 extends HttpServlet{

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String str=request.getParameter("pitches");
        String[] str2 = str.split(",");
        System.out.println("Str =" + str2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're getting a String of numbers separated by commas, and want to parse it into a list of doubles.

`String.split()` allows splitting a String on a separator.

`Double.valueOf()` allows transforming a String into a Double. Combine these two methods, and you have your answer.

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is there to explain how to use these methods.

Comment: I updated my question to include my current servlet code.  When I run it, I get the following output: Str =[Ljava.lang.String;@5e91498b

Comment: Use `System.out.println("Str = " + java.util.Arrays.toString(str2));` to print an array. The toString() method of an array only returns its type ([Ljava.lang.String;) followed by its hashCode, i.e. nothing really meaningful.

Comment: This was successful:

        String str = request.getParameter("pitches").toString();
        String[] str2 = str.split(" ");
        String str3 = Arrays.toString(str2).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "");